# What is the "Control" in Control.ControlCollection class?

Tags: c#

MSDN page on this class has a [Control.ControlCollection (Control) constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.controlcollection.aspx).

But the syntax only uses ControlCollection. I am puzzled as to what the "Control" before the dot operator represent.

Thanks

Comment: please post the link where this was found so we know what you're referencing

Comment: The parent control because a control can contain child controls

Comment: It is a nested class.  There are 4 distinct ControlCollection classes.  The one you found plus Form.ControlCollection, MdiClient.ControlCollection and TabControl.Collection.  They derive from Control.ControlCollection to override the Add and Remove methods.  Not otherwise relevant to your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ControlCollection` is a nested class, inside the `Control` class. This example should make it clearer:

```
public class Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        public Bar() { }
    }
}

var bar = new Foo.Bar();
```

In your case `Foo` is `Control` and `Bar` is `ControlCollection`, and the Syntax section refers to the `public Bar()` part.

Comment: and `control` is the base class for windows form controls:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I forget the parameter the constructor. That does make it clear. I was wondering how a nested class of the base Control class has information about ControlCollection of its derived controls.